# How to implement Download function by importing files from JSON file into ReactJS file

Tags: reactjs, json

I am unable to integrate certificate files from a JSON file into my ReactJS file. I want to implement the functionality to download the certificate upon clicking the "course" field. I have tried this which worked statically in other file but its not working int this case, i want to download the files by importing it directly from JSON file.

**data.json**

```
{
    "projects": [
        
        {
            "date": "2017 - 2018",
            "title": "St. Patrick's School",
            "course": "S.S.C.",
            "certificate": "./Documents/SSC.pdf"
        },
        {
          "date": "25/02/2023 - 25/03/2023",
          "title": "Cascode",
          "course": "Web Development",
          "certificate": "./Documents/CasCodeCertificate.pdf"
        },
        
        {
            "date": "2019 - 2020",
            "title": "St. Vincent's College",
            "course": "H.S.C.",
            "certificate": "./Documents/HSC.pdf"
        },
        {
          "date": "05/03/2023 - 05/04/2023",
          "title": "SYNC Intern",
          "course": "Software Development",
          "certificate": "./Documents/SYNC.pdf"
        },
        {
            "date": "2021 - 2024",
            "title": "SAE, Kondhawa",
            "course": "BTECH in Computer Engineering",
            "certificate": "./Documents/Btech.pdf"
        }
    ]
  }
```

**Timeline.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import data from "../assets/data.json";

const Timeline = () => {
    return (
        <div id='timeline'>
            <div className="timelineBox">
                {data.projects.map((item, index) => (
                    <TimelineItem heading={item.title} text={item.date} course={item.course} index={index} key={item.title} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const TimelineItem = ({ heading, text, course, index, certificate }) => (
    <div className={`timelineItem ${index % 2 === 0 ? "leftTimeline" : "rightTimeline"}`}>
        <div className="timelineItemBox">
            <a href={certificate} download="certificate"><h2 className='courseField'>{course}</h2></a>
            <p>{heading}</p>
            <p className='date'>{text}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
)

export default Timeline
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
const downloadHandler = async (address, filename) => {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const url = await window.URL.createObjectURL(address);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    a.click();
  };
```

and use this function like this:

```
const TimelineItem = ({ heading, text, course, index, certificate }) => (
    <div className={`timelineItem ${index % 2 === 0 ? "leftTimeline" : "rightTimeline"}`}>
        <div className="timelineItemBox">
            <button onClick={() => downloadHandler(address=certificate, fileName=title)}><h2 className='courseField'>{course}</h2></a>
            <p>{heading}</p>
            <p className='date'>{text}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```